# Regex to check credit card numbers

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expressions and trying to write a program to see if the user enters a credit card number that is in a valid range(within the range of 13 to 16 and all digits). Following is the java code I have written and my regular expression doesn't take care of my need.

```
//Credit card number 1234567891234567 matched against regex
boolean b = Pattern.matches("4\ d{ 12} (\ d{ 3} )?", "1234567891234567");
if(b==true)
{
        System.out.println("credit card is valid");
}
else
{
        System.out.println("credit card is not valid");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the requirement?

Comment: All the spaces in your regex pattern are definitely a problem.

Comment: Don't forget the check digit. Just checking by a regex for the lenght does not make it a valid cc number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite simple.  Here's your Regex:

```
"\\d{13,16}"
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been solved before using the [Luhn formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). Here is a [Java implementation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Luhn_test_of_credit_card_numbers#Java)